# The call is ambiguous between the following methods for video streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a problem with this ASP.NET API controller.

```
response.Content = new PushStreamContent(video.WriteToStream, 
                                         new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/" + ext));
```

And I get this error :

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'PushStreamContent.PushStreamContent(Action, MediaTypeHeaderValue)' and 'PushStreamContent.PushStreamContent(Func, MediaTypeHeaderValue)'
>     TVStream    G:\TVStream\TVStream\Controllers\Api\VideosController.cs    19  Active

And here is the signature of my WriteToStream method:

```
public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
```

Comment: Are there two overloads of the `video.WriteToStream` method? If not what is the signature of the method?

Comment: I'm not positive if this will be helpful, but I'm guessing it has to do with your first parameter?  I looks like the 2 methods it's showing are ambiguous only difference is the first parameter.  One looks for an Action<...> and the other one looks like a Func<...>.  What is the type of video.WriteToStream?  And is it generic enough that it could be either one of those?

Comment: Could you post `video.WriteToStream` method signature

Comment: `public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)` here is the signature of my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `void` method to return `Task` which somewhat represents asynchronous `void` method.

```
public Task WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
```

I'm not sure why is this happening, but if you want to stick to your `async void` signature, you can use intermediate variable:

```
Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext> writeToStream = WriteToStream;
response.Content = new PushStreamContent(writeToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/" + ext));
```